# Can't connect using mysql_connect to Database in ipage.com hosting?

Tags: php, mysql

I have purchased hosting space from **ipage.com** . I have been developing android app , and I need to connect to my database to get some data from my table. I got some `php` code to get the data from database in **JSON** format.

the php code is as follows :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^ E_DEPRECATED);
$con = mysql_connect("server","user_name","password"); 
//what should be entered in server ??
{

if(!$con)
  {  
    die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());
     }

mysql_select_db("getlatlng",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM latlng");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{  $output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I have a domain name arunyadav.in linked to the server. 
I am unable to connect to it , please let me know , how to connect to it(I am a newbie here).

Comment: What is your db software? is it phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes , it is phpmyadmin.

Comment: Then go to phpmyadmin there you get server name

Comment: i tried the server name , but it doesn't connect to it . 
I even tried to open the server link in new tab , it is  [link](custsql-ipg82.eigbox.net) , but it doesnt work even

Comment: `mysql_connect` i deprecated try `mysqli_connect`

Comment: i already know that , but it can be used using
error_reporting(E_ALL^ E_DEPRECATED);

I even tried to connect using mysqli_connect.
Still the same problem

Comment: is your die function wiorkng? what is the output of `mysql_error()`

Comment: i dont know, i am new to php , dont know hoe to do work on it , but got the code from someone which i used on localhost and worked perfectly fine.

Comment: what is showing when this pgm executed?

Comment: i provided the server value and username password of my database and the script showed the error as :

Could not connect:Unknown MySQL server host 'custsql-ipg82.eigbox.net' (111)

Comment: Have you tried using `localhost` as your hostname? Also, as others have pointed out, use MySQLi instead (the error you're getting is not if you use MySQL or MySQLi - it's that you're assigning to a host that's _not actually_ a SQL server.

Comment: localhost works only when i work on database on my laptop , i.e. on local system , to connect through server , database url is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer... the server name it shows within server is different and don't allow to connect , while the creating DB server page have a different server name , which is actually in the format :

username.ipagemysql.com

This Worked , and i got the answer.
Phpmyadmin was providing some other address which actually is shown as address for server , but was something else

Comment: so how the database name will be?